# I am trying to label data and am getting a syntax error, but I cannot understand where it is

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
neighbourhoods_venues_sorted.insert(neighborhoods_venues_sorted.drop(['Cluster Labels'], axis=1, inplace=True)
neighbourhoods_venues_sorted.insert(0, 'Cluster Labels', kmeans.labels_ )

mumbai_merged = df

# merge madrid_grouped with df_madrid to add latitude/longitude for each neighbourhood
mumbai_merged = mumbai_merged.join(neighbourhoods_venues_sorted.set_index('Neighbourhood'), on='Neighbourhood')

mumbai_merged.head()
```

Here the error I am getting:

```
  File "<ipython-input-65-82099c452820>", line 3
    neighbourhoods_venues_sorted.insert(0, 'Cluster Labels', kmeans.labels_ )
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing a `)` in the line above, hence the SyntaxError.